# Is this a safe way to load objects from vector of uint8_t by pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a `std::vector<uint8_t> buffer`; I want to load a datatype which is larger than `uint8_t` (in this example `uint16_t target`, but could be anything). I know that the content of this object has been copied into position `size_t ID` in `buffer`.

As far as I can tell, it is possible to copy the `target` with:

```
uint16_t target = *((uint16_t*) &buffer[ID]);
```

It works with `gcc version 9.3.0` on Ubuntu using C++17.

But it certainly looks unintended. So is this safe to use? That is, as long as I know for certain that `ID+sizeof(target)` is within the buffer, can I be sure that this will compile and run without crashing on all OS?

Comment: You could have alignment issues on some platforms I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it isn't. You cannot "pretend" a `uint16_t` exists where it does not.

There are some circumstances where such type punning is safe. For example, you can reinterpret an existing object of your desired type as a sequence of bytes (through a `char*`, `unsigned char*` or `std::byte*`), but the opposite is not true. *([ref](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#11))*

C++ is quite picky about what objects "exist", and you have to follow the rules of the language to make objects exist properly before you use them. It's not all just bytes. The compiler's "optimisations" can break your program's intended behaviour even before we get to the lower-level issues of alignment etc on actual computers.

To make this safe, you will need to copy the bytes into a fresh `uint16_t`:

```
uint16_t target = 0;
std::copy(
   reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&buffer[ID]),
   reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&buffer[ID]) + sizeof(uint16_t),
   reinterpret_cast<char*>(&target)
);
```

… or the shorter:

```
uint16_t target = 0;
std::memcpy(&target, &buffer[ID], sizeof(uint16_t));
```

Notice that here we are making use of the aliasing exemption I described above, to reinterpret a `uint16_t` as a sequence of bytes, writing into that sequence.

So, these versions are safe, as long as the bytes you are copying indeed form a valid representation of a `uint16_t` on your system (which is quite easy to guarantee for mainstream platforms).

Comment: This is a case where std::memcpy is less yuck than std::copy in my opinion.

Comment: @eerorika Granted it can be shorter. I don't like the complete lack of type safety though. I've seen bugs where someone's replaced an array with a `std::map` without checking all usages, and `memcpy`/`memset` operations that should never have been written in the first place silently kept on blatting bytes until a crash in production revealed the issue. Though to be fair that's not a brilliant example, as the language's checks on those casts should take care of the problem first.

Comment: Wouldn't `reinterpret_cast` + `std::copy` also "keep blatting bytes until crash". I don't see how they are safer.

Comment: @eerorika Yeah to be fair that example is less than useless isn't it  It was really a case where a `std::memset` should have been replaced by a `std::map::clear`. Had it been a `std::vector` instead, the original `std::memset` would ideally have been a `std::fill` and then the type change would have shown up in a compilation error. That would be a better example but still not relevant to this question. Oh well!

Comment: Isn't the memcpy thing the implementation for c++20 std::bit_cast?

Comment: @JVApen [Yep](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast). I can't see a way to use it to grab the bytes from some subset of an array of bytes though.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I will use memcpy then, it even looks more readable than my current notation.

Comment: I wanted to notice that C++20 `std::bit_cast` could be a better alternative to `std::memcpy`, but `bit_cast` requires that the source and destination types are the same size, which is not the case here.

Comment: @JVApen This would be a legal way to implement `std::bit_cast`. But I think it would be a bit silly, since `bit_cast` is basically a (well defined) no-op. I checked on MSVC, and there it is implemented as `__builtin_bit_cast`.